# OpenIddict Client not passing default scopes to authentication request

Tags: openiddict

When adding a client registration in OpenIddict (via `OpenIddictClientRegistration`), the registration class has a [`Scopes`](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/eb1fcc82bd98e47bceaa19fc01da546a4c452604/src/OpenIddict.Client/OpenIddictClientRegistration.cs#L150-L153) property with the description:

> Gets the list of scopes sent by default as part of authorization requests.

I am attempting to use this for any scopes I want to be on the token by default:

```cs
options.AddRegistration(new OpenIddictClientRegistration
{
    // ...
    Scopes =
    {
        "scope1",
        //...
        "scopeN",
    },
    // ...
});
```

However when the `OpenIddictClientService` goes on to call `AuthenticateWithClientCredentialsAsync` it does not seem to set these scopes on the `ProcessAuthenticationContext` it creates, so will only ever use the list of scopes passed directly to the `AuthenticateWithClientCredentialsAsync` method.

The registration itself is [passed into the context](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/eb1fcc82bd98e47bceaa19fc01da546a4c452604/src/OpenIddict.Client/OpenIddictClientService.cs#L361-L375), but this does not seem to have any bearing on the [scopes](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/eb1fcc82bd98e47bceaa19fc01da546a4c452604/src/OpenIddict.Client/OpenIddictClientEvents.cs#L351-L354) used.

Am I misunderstanding how the `Scopes` property on the `OpenIddictClientRegistration` should work or is there something else I need to set in order for these scopes to be passed by default with any request?

Answer (score 2):

It's the expected behavior: this property is only used for interactive grants involving users like the code flow or the device authorization flow. For non-interactive grants like the client credentials grant, you must set `ClientCredentialsAuthenticationRequest` explicitly:

```cs
var result = await _service.AuthenticateWithClientCredentialsAsync(new()
{
    Scopes = ["my_scope"]
});
```